# Windows 10 can't see firebase in my PATH

Tags: windows, firebase, path, installation, firebase-tools

I tried to install firebase:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

but then I tried:

```
firebase login
```

and failed with:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

But I have global npm folder in my PATH.
I have yarn & flow and it works fine
[image]

My PATH looks like this:

[image]

and my npm folder (you can see firebase, yarn, flow there):
[image]

- reboot doesn't work
- reopening my cmd doesn't work too

Please help.

Comment: tried to reinstall npm - now ```which firebase``` works and I see the path, but after ```firebase``` I see ```The system cannot find the path specified.```

Comment: reinstall npm & reinstall firebase

Answer (score 4):

I know It's a bit late but here is my fix:

1. After running `npm install -g firebase-tools` open your File explorer at this location: `C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm`
2. Shift + Right Click to open PowerShell at this location and then enter `./firebase`. If this works, great!
3. Open environment variables and add `C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm` to your path for current user AND System variables
4. Restart your machine
5. Use firebase #Yay

Hope it helps!

Comment: Note that PowerShell may give the following error at #2 when trying `./firebase`: _"cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system"_ but CMD won't. Regardless, adding `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm` in the system PATH fixes this